# I don't know how to md5 my password in iPhone ,or how to start

Tags: iphone, passwords, md5, commoncrypto

I don't know how to md5 my password in iPhone ,or how to start.
I tried to know something like CommonCrypto.Will help?
urgely for a suggestion~
thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer / question on the Apple Forums actually has several valid implementations of an md5 hash on the iPhone: https://discussions.apple.com/message/7362074?messageID=7362074#7362074?messageID=7362074.

Comment: it works. thanks~ https://discussions.apple.com/message/7362074?messageID=7362074#7362074?messageID=7362074                             // Function definition
NSString * md5( NSString *str )
{
const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
unsigned char result[CCMD5_DIGESTLENGTH];
CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );
return [NSString 
stringWithFormat: @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
result[0], result[1],
result[2], result[3],
result[4], result[5],
result[6], result[7],
result[8], result[9],
result[10], result[11],
result[12], result[13],
result[14], result[15]
];
}

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer, to show others that the issue has been resolved :)

Comment: here again~ I wonder where CommonCrypto belongs~cause"One of my iPhone apps uses the <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h> framework for calculating hashes. There is plenty of documentation in the XCode doc sets on the subject. Do a full text search in All Doc Sets for 'CommonDigest'. You will find the CC_MD5 man pages. (For new applications it is preferred to use SHA-256.)

In the iPhone Simulator it all works fine. I can not test it on the iPhone itself"   Does this mean CommonCrypto doesn't belong to iOS SDK but MAC OS SDK?

Comment: It's a Mac command~sigh~~Mac OS X Manual Page For CC_MD5_Final(3cc) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/CC_MD5_Final.3cc.html

Comment: They seem to get it to work on iOS here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480883/how-to-use-common-crypto.